# unable to access, requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: python, github, terminal, repository, permission-denied

I'm still kinda new to coding so this might be a simple fix, but I ran into this error while trying to make and work with a git repository

```
git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://Patty-y@github.com':
remote: Permission to Patty-y/Origin.git denied to Patty-y.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Patty-y/Origin.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

keep in mind Patty-y is me, my repository is public, yet access was denied to me? I don't exactly understand that, and thank you all in advance for helping me out!

I successfully made a repository on git called Origin and I was planning to bring some data into the repository for a project of mine. I logged in and used the token password thing, yet for some reason permission was denied to the repository. I wasn't expecting that, of course, and I just need some help to push through till my next error lol

Comment: Simplest explanation is that you typed the wrong username or password...